# Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built - Gradle on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

When building a maven project on Jenkins its possible to specify the build trigger:

**Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built**

This works out of the box.

I have a Gradle project that I build with gradle (v. 1.2) on Jenkins (ver. 1.483) using Artifactory as my binary storage. But cannot find the same option. Are there any Gradle plugins for Jenkins that enables this functionality or is it possible to configure it globally in a .gradle file?